# Getting window.location path from URL

Tags: javascript, url, get, routes, window.location

I would like to create website with different languages.

The structure would look like this:

```
www.website.com/en/*
www.website.com/fr/*
www.website.com/de/*
```

The path to en fr or de does not exist, but I would like to make the main page to read from the URL after slash to determine the language.

I have tried examples with hash:

```
var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
alert(type);
```

This would work with the link www.website.com/index.html#something
It would alert something, but I am not able to make this work with a path name since the directory/path en, fr or de does not exists.

Is there a smarter way of doing it without creating the actual folders of the languages ?

The expected result would be: 
User goes to `www.website.com/fr` and the message `'Your language is French'` could be alerted without making any directories, just reading it from the URL.

It should be vanilla JS not a framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `window.location.pathname`, which gives you the path of your browser URL. Something like `alert(window.location.pathname)` will alert `en` for URL `www.website.com/en`.

Comment: Yes but when you navigate from the home page it e.g www.website.com/en it will not read this function because it is in the root direcotry and therefore I wouldget object not found error

Comment: you can use .htaccess for these kind of things.

Comment: @KevinKloet the question was about javascript, so you are saying it is not possible ?

Comment: As @KevinKloet pointed out, you have to redirect `/en/*`, `/fr/*`, `/de/*` paths to your main page. You can't do this on the browser side.

Comment: no this can't be done in javascript, you would need to do this server side with .htaccess as i noted above.

Comment: Well techically speaking, it *could be* done in browser side javascript, **but the server has to return page with that javascript for any valid path** - .htaccess / web.config